# how to plot a chart on Bokeh with dropdown options

Tags: pandas, bokeh

**Use Case :**

i have a data frame which constitutes of below records

```
    suite_name  fail  Pass      Report_datetime
0  VOLTE-VOLTE     5     8  2017-11-14 00:00:00
1     4G-VOLTE     5     6  2017-11-13 00:00:00
2    New-VOLTE     5     9  2017-11-10 00:00:00
```

I want to plot this data on bokeh in form of Bar Chart(or any other type), where user will have two drop down option

1)suite_name

2)Report_datetime

User should be able to select data from drop down and result is displayed in form of chart 
e.g. user want to see the data of 'suite_name' =4G-Volte on "Report_datetime" 2017-11-13 00:00:00
he should be able to see number of 'Fail', 'Pass'

**What i did till now ?**

I have tried to plot a basic bar chart, but don't know how to proceed further with my use case.

here is what i did

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
var=6
var1=9
d={'fail':[var1],'Pass':[var]}
#d = {'col1': [var1], 'col2': [var1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df


p=figure(x_range=['fail','Pass'])
p.vbar(x=['fail','Pass'], top=[var,var1],width=0.4)
output_file("bar.html")
show(p)
```

Any guidance or suggestion would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
suite_dropdown = Dropdown(label="Select Suite", menu=['VOLTE-VOLTE','4G-VOLTE','New-VOLTE'])

report_dropdown = Dropdown(label="Select Time", menu=['2017-11-14 00:00:00','2017-11-13 00:00:00,'2017-11-10 00:00:00'])

show(widgetbox(children = [suite_dropdown,report_dropdown], sizing_mode = "fixed"))
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be useful.

Comment: DropDown is used to create dropdown widgets and the menu is the list of values.